# Show XML data in three columns per row using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt-1.0

I have following XML data in which I want to show recipes in three columns per row. I want to show title, serves and image node of recipe tag in a td with 3 td's per row and following searched recipes in next row.

```
<recipeList>
    <recipe id="ch02_recipe020">
        <title>Spinach and zucchini frittata</title>
        <serves>Serves 4</serves>
        <ingredientList>
            <ingredientEntry>
                <ingredientQty>1 tablespoon</ingredientQty>
                <keyIngredient>olive oil</keyIngredient>
            </ingredientEntry>
            <ingredientEntry>
                <ingredientQty>1</ingredientQty>
                <keyIngredient>red onion</keyIngredient>, thinly sliced

            </ingredientEntry>

        </ingredientList>
        <prepSteps>
            <prepStep>
                <para>Heat the oil in a medium non-stick frying pan and fry the onion and zucchini over medium heat until they are a pale golden brown. Add the garlic and cook it for a minute. Add the spinach and cook until the spinach has wilted and any excess moisture has evaporated off — if you don't do this, your frittata will end up soggy in the middle, as the liquid will continue to come out as it cooks. Shake the pan so you get an even layer of mixture. Turn the heat down to low.</para>
            </prepStep>

        </prepSteps>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/01075/091.jpg" />
        </figure>

    </recipe>
    <recipe id="ch02_recipe026">
        <title>Bacon and avocado salad</title>
        <serves>Serves 4</serves>
        <ingredientList>
            <ingredientEntry>
                <ingredientQty>8</ingredientQty>
                <keyIngredient>bacon rashers</keyIngredient>, rinds cut off

            </ingredientEntry>

        </ingredientList>
        <prepSteps>
            <prepStep>
                <para>Turn on the grill (broiler). Put the bacon on a tray and grill on both sides until it is nice and crisp. Leave it to cool and then break into pieces.</para>
            </prepStep>
            <prepStep>
                <para>Bring a saucepan of water to the boil and cook the beans for 4 minutes. Drain and then hold them under cold running water for a few seconds to stop them cooking any further.</para>
            </prepStep>

        </prepSteps>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/01075/103.jpg" />
        </figure>

    </recipe>
    <recipe id="ch02_recipe028">
        <title>Spinach salad with chicken and sesame dressing</title>
        <serves>Serves 4</serves>
        <ingredientList>
            <ingredientEntry>
                <ingredientQty>450 g (1 lb)</ingredientQty>
                <keyIngredient>baby English spinach leaves</keyIngredient>
            </ingredientEntry>
            <ingredientEntry>
                <ingredientQty>1</ingredientQty>
                <keyIngredient>Lebanese (short) cucumber</keyIngredient>, peeled and diced

            </ingredientEntry>

        </ingredientList>
        <prepSteps>
            <prepStep>
                <para>Put the spinach in a large bowl. Scatter the cucumber, spring onion and carrot over the top. Shred the chicken breast into long pieces and scatter it over the vegetables.</para>
            </prepStep>

        </prepSteps>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/01075/107.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <file src="MB Pages/Lunch.qxd" />
    </recipe>
    <recipe id="ch03_recipe025">
        <title>Tandoori chicken with cardamom rice</title>
        <serves>Serves 4</serves>
        <ingredientList>
            <ingredientEntry>
                <ingredientQty>250 ml (1 cup)</ingredientQty>
                <keyIngredient>natural yoghurt</keyIngredient>, plus extra for serving

            </ingredientEntry>

        </ingredientList>
        <prepSteps>
            <prepStep>
                <para>Soak eight wooden skewers in water for 30 minutes to prevent them burning during cooking. Combine the yoghurt, tandoori paste and lemon juice in a non-metallic dish. Add the chicken and coat well, then cover and marinate for at least 10 minutes.</para>
            </prepStep>

        </prepSteps>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/01075/174.jpg" />
        </figure>
        <file src="MB Pages/Casual 124-185.qxd" />
    </recipe>

</recipeList>
```

I am using below XSLT but it is not displaying 3 records per row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!-- Designed by SoftServ Solutions, February 13, 2017 -->
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:m="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"
                xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <xsl:output method="html" indent="yes" encoding="windows-1252" />
    <xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <html>
        <head>
            <title>Murdoch Books DIY</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="recipeList" />
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:output indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
<xsl:param name="cols">3</xsl:param> <!-- set the number of rows here -->
<xsl:template match="recipeList">
    <table width="30%" align="center" border="1">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="recipe[position() mod $cols = 1 or position() = 1]" mode="row" />
    </table>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recipe" mode="row">
    <tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::title[position() &lt; $cols]" mode="cell" />

    </tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="recipe" mode="cell">
    <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="title" />
        <xsl:value-of select="serves" />
        <br />
        <xsl:if test="figure">
            <xsl:apply-templates select="figure" />
        </xsl:if>
    </td>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="figure">
    <p align="left">
        <img width="25%" height="25%">
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
            <xsl:value-of select="img/@src" />
        </xsl:attribute>
        </img>
    </p>
    <a>
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
        </xsl:attribute>
    </a>
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="caption" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="source" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can anyone please help? I am new to XSLT.

Comment: Your requirement is not clear. Do you want to have a table with 3 columns (one recipe per row, 3 cells per recipe), or a table with 9 columns (3 recipes per row, with 3 cells each)?

Comment: Sorry, I was not clear. I need a table with 3 columns per row, each column will have recipe title tag and thumbnail image. If there are 7 records in my search result then my table will show 3 rows with first 2 rows having 6 recipe (3 columns) and last row having one recipe (one column). thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change this part:

```
<xsl:template match="recipe" mode="row">
    <tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::title[position() &lt; $cols]" mode="cell" />

    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="recipe" mode="row">
    <tr>

        <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::recipe[position() &lt; $cols]" mode="cell" />

    </tr>
</xsl:template>
```

---

While you're at it, you could remove the redundancy here:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="recipe[position() mod $cols = 1 or position() = 1]" mode="row" />
```

and make it simply:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="recipe[position() mod $cols = 1]" mode="row" />
```

You also have two `xsl:output` elements, and both `<xsl:preserve-space elements="*" />` and `xsl:strip-space elements="*" />` which makes very little sense. Those are just a few things I have noticed, there may be more.